# Double dual Spaces and the annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I am revising linear algebra, and am a bit stuck on this problem.

So, if you define a natural isomorphism $f$ between $V$ and its double dual $V''$, you get $$f:V\rightarrow V''$$
$$v\mapsto E_v$$ where, $$E_v(f)=f(v),\forall v \in V'$$
I am then asked to show, that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, under this natural isomorphism, $f|_U$ is a bijection between $U$ and $U^{00}$.

I am not sure how to do this, I see that if $u$ is mapped to its evaluation map, then the evaluation map on all the functions in $U^0$ is clearly 0, but from here, I do not know how to show the bijection.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you want $E:V\to V''$ and $\forall v\in V,\forall \phi\in V',\ E_v(\phi)=\phi(v)$. The thing you wrote as a definition is just confusing.

Comment: Also, what's $U^0$?

Comment: $U^0=\{ f\in V':f(u)=0 \forall u '\in U \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some different approach:

For given vector space $V$ and its subspace $U$, $ dim U + dim U^0 = dim V$.

Also, by taking dual, $ dim U^0 + dim U^{00} = dim V^* $.

Since $dim V = dim V^*$, this results $dim U = dim U^{00}$.

By definition, $U$ is a subspace of $U^{00}$.

Hence $dim U = dim U^{00}$ implies $ U = U^{00}$.

Comment: also I recommend you to refer K.Hoffman's <Linear Algebra>. it might help you to study the dual spaces.